# How do I create a two column div layout where each column can have variable width

Tags: css, layout, html

I think the best way is to show us an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/w6MKU/) :

I'd like to have a div with the user/date info, another div with the text (which should go in a new line if it's longer than the div width) and another div with a link.

How you can see, the first line haven't problem (its correct). The second one, put the div as "block"... seems that float is ignored.

Any helps?

**EDIT**

Taking the jsfiddler as example, the output should be somethings like this one :

```
04-03-2011 - userA - Hello My name is John and I really like this website                               X 
02-04-2010 - userA-RealGoodUser -  This text should be at the right of the userA-RealGoodUser, but      X
                                   in fact it doesnt. Why this behaviour?
```

Comment: Does the text on the new line want to go underneath the user/date? or be inline with the starte of the first line?

Comment: Addedan example, maybe it make more clear :)

Comment: if you were to set the width of `wallMess` you'll get the wrapping that you want

Comment: I'd also like that the wallMess is auto :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated code as well**

```
.wallArea {
    width: 700px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: #000000;
    float: left;
}

.wallArea1 {
    width: 670px;
    float: left;
    color: #000000;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.wallArea2 {
    width: 20px;
    float: left;
    color: #000000;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 2px;
}

.wallUser {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    font-family: comic sans ms;
    font-style: oblique;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.wallMess {
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: comic sans ms;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

**Update based on example**

See it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w6MKU/6/).  I basically allow both columns (user and mess areas) to autosize.  This should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Uhm yes, but I need a sort of dinamic width, that's why I put width:auto on the walluser and wallMess....

Comment: That is just making the width of the div containing the text auto.  The size of the box containing those div's is not auto, and needs to be wide enough to handle the text, otherwise it will wrap

Comment: If you want it to fit and be dynamic, change the `wallArea1` width to `auto`

Comment: `wallArea`, the div surrounding `wallArea1` will then be the constraining div, so you'll need to adjust that too.

Comment: @markzzz - I updated my answer.  The two columns should autosize based on the amount of text.  Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Uhm...using that overflow:hidden and width:auto, sometime it works, sometime no (using chrome)... (I think a bug...)

Answer (score 1):

Your containing div, `wallArea1` is smaller than the content, `wallUser` and `wallMess` therefore `wallMess` gets pushed to the next line. If you increase the width of `wallArea1` and its containing div `wallArea` this doesn't happen.